# function Set of Firebase to insert data in RealTime Database is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to the v9 of Firebase so i am using the new functions. I am trying to insert data into RealTime Database of Firebase, using SET.

FIRST IMPORT AND INITIALIZE THE VARIABLES

```
<script type="module">
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    const myfrom = document.getElementById("rateF");
    
    import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-app.js";
    import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-analytics.js";
    import { getDatabase, ref, set, push } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.0/firebase-database.js";
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
        ...
     };
     const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
     const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
     const database = getDatabase(app);
```

Than i start the actual function called on submit

```
    myfrom.addEventListener ("submit",(e) =>validate());
    function validate(){
        var select = document.getElementById('titolo');
        var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        var comment = document.getElementById('comm').value;
        var radio = getValueRadio();


        console.log(value);
        console.log(comment);
        console.log(radio);

        sendMessage(value,comment,radio);
    }
```

THE FUNCTION WHERE I USE SET

```
    function sendMessage(value,comment,radio){

        const db = getDatabase();
        const postListRef = ref(database,"comment");

        set(postListRef,{
            from: "admin",
            film: value,
            comment: comment,
            rate: radio
        })
        .then(()=>{
            alert("Commento Inviato");
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            alert("error");
            console.log(error)
        });

    }


    function getValueRadio(){
     ...
    }
  </script>
```

The set actually doesn't send any alert of any kind. The functions just start anf finish with no errors but the data is not inserted.
What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: If inside `validate`, you instead do `set(ref(getDatabase(), "test"), true);` does that work? If not, check the JavaScript console of your browser for errors.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the RealTime Database still doesn't change. And in the console there is no error

Comment: Are you sure the code actually executes? I.e. if you set a breakpoint on the `set` line and run in the debugger, does it actually reach that line?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes, the debugger reaches this line

Comment: Interesting: if the write fails there should be an error logged. If that doesn't happen, it usually means there's no internet connection, but in a web scenario that is unusual. I'm not sure what's going on. Hopefully somebody else spots it. Otherwise: can you reproduce this in a site like jsbin/stackblitz, so that I can have a look?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it would be perfect for me

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-urstt6?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.html

Comment: When I click `Submit` there, I see `Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Do you get that same message locally? If so: https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+Error%3A+Cannot+use+import+statement+outside+a+module

Comment: locally it doesn't appear unfortunately. Just no response about this function when is executed. No error or anything else

Comment: OK. Thanks for trying. Let me know if you can reproduce it in that StackBlitz or elsewhere and I'll have another look.